# Array field presence in Symfony Validator

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

What's the Symfony Validator way of dealing with the case when a key in an array must exist but the value can be empty? [This doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html#required-and-optional-field-constraints) says about the `Optional` constraint, but this constraint allows the key to be missing in the array.

Say my code expects the following structure:

```
['foo'=>'bar', 'baz'=>'']
```

How do I get the Validator to complain when the `baz` key is missing? It can be empty though. Also is where a way to make sure it follows a constraint if it's not empty?

For example Laravel has the [`present` constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-present). Do I really have to code `array_key_exists` manually? Must be a very common case.

Also is it possible to validate a collection by the prototype of its element, just like the Configuration component can do?

Comment: have you tried the allowMissingFields option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) and implement a callback validation assert and do an array_key_exist or follow the same logic and add the allowMissingFields option.